# Python dictionary inserting values as Tuples and instead of float

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to fetch tickers on different cryptocurrencies, and add the related values of those cryptocurrencies to a flat dictionary so that I may save their values and items as 2 separate lists late on.

I need all the values of my dictionary to be either of the type int or float.
However, I am running into this problem where, when adding to my dictionary, python is converting the the type of my value to a tuple, whether or not I parse it to a float before inserting it into the dictionary.

The value types on the ticker I have are as followed:

[image: Ticker Values]

The json value of the ticker, if anyone would like to run it:

```
{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'priceChange': '1170.82000000', 'priceChangePercent': '4.519', 'weightedAvgPrice': '27116.45253287', 'prevClosePrice': '25909.19000000', 'lastPrice': '27080.01000000', 'lastQty': '0.00126000', 'bidPrice': '27080.00000000', 'bidQty': '2.34551500', 'askPrice': '27080.01000000', 'askQty': '1.48636700', 'openPrice': '25909.19000000', 'highPrice': '28422.00000000', 'lowPrice': '25810.56000000', 'volume': '153836.68308900', 'quoteVolume': '4171505114.79728177', 'openTime': 1609012754503, 'closeTime': 1609099154503, 'firstId': 527277428, 'lastId': 529816566, 'count': 2539139}
```

Here is my code for generating the list:

```
crypto_value_inputs = {}
for crypto in cryptos:
    s = crypto['symbol']
    ticker = tickers[s]
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_last_price"] = float(ticker['lastPrice'])
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_change_percent"] = float(ticker['priceChangePercent']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_average_price"] = float(ticker['weightedAvgPrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_open_price"] = float(ticker['openPrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_last_close_price"] = float(ticker['prevClosePrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_last_quantity"] = float(ticker['lastQty']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_bid_price"] = float(ticker['bidPrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_bid_quantity"] = float(ticker['bidQty']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_ask_price"] = float(ticker['askPrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_ask_quantity"] = float(ticker['askQty']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_high_price"] = float(ticker['highPrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_low_price"] = float(ticker['lowPrice']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_volume"] = float(ticker['volume']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_quote_volume"] = float(ticker['quoteVolume']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_open_time"] = float(ticker['openTime']),
    crypto_value_inputs[s + "_close_time"] = float(ticker['closeTime'])
return crypto_value_inputs
```

And here are the value types:

[image: Crypto Value Type]

The actual JSON value of the output dictionary:

```
{'BTCUSDT_last_price': 27080.01, 'BTCUSDT_change_percent': (4.519,), 'BTCUSDT_average_price': (27116.45253287,), 'BTCUSDT_open_price': (25909.19,), 'BTCUSDT_last_close_price': (25909.19,), 'BTCUSDT_last_quantity': (0.00126,), 'BTCUSDT_bid_price': (27080.0,), 'BTCUSDT_bid_quantity': (2.345515,), 'BTCUSDT_ask_price': (27080.01,), 'BTCUSDT_ask_quantity': (1.486367,), 'BTCUSDT_high_price': (28422.0,), 'BTCUSDT_low_price': (25810.56,), 'BTCUSDT_volume': (153836.683089,), 'BTCUSDT_quote_volume': (4171505114.7972817,), 'BTCUSDT_open_time': (1609012754503.0,), 'BTCUSDT_close_time': 1609099154503.0, 'ETHUSDT_last_price': 705.41, 'ETHUSDT_change_percent': (9.269,), 'ETHUSDT_average_price': (665.33076424,), 'ETHUSDT_open_price': (645.57,), 'ETHUSDT_last_close_price': (645.57,), 'ETHUSDT_last_quantity': (0.61474,), 'ETHUSDT_bid_price': (705.39,), 'ETHUSDT_bid_quantity': (0.61474,), 'ETHUSDT_ask_price': (705.41,), 'ETHUSDT_ask_quantity': (3.71429,), 'ETHUSDT_high_price': (717.13,), 'ETHUSDT_low_price': (625.0,), 'ETHUSDT_volume': (1747976.61878,), 'ETHUSDT_quote_volume': (1162982619.6446111,), 'ETHUSDT_open_time': (1609012754510.0,), 'ETHUSDT_close_time': 1609099154510.0, 'ETCUSDT_last_price': 5.9665, 'ETCUSDT_change_percent': (3.603,), 'ETCUSDT_average_price': (5.85436613,), 'ETCUSDT_open_price': (5.759,), 'ETCUSDT_last_close_price': (5.7553,), 'ETCUSDT_last_quantity': (10.62,), 'ETCUSDT_bid_price': (5.9645,), 'ETCUSDT_bid_quantity': (100.0,), 'ETCUSDT_ask_price': (5.9662,), 'ETCUSDT_ask_quantity': (11.54,), 'ETCUSDT_high_price': (6.1197,), 'ETCUSDT_low_price': (5.4914,), 'ETCUSDT_volume': (4916271.75,), 'ETCUSDT_quote_volume': (28781654.820338,), 'ETCUSDT_open_time': (1609012751019.0,), 'ETCUSDT_close_time': 1609099151019.0, 'XRPUSDT_last_price': 0.29512, 'XRPUSDT_change_percent': (-0.727,), 'XRPUSDT_average_price': (0.29250503,), 'XRPUSDT_open_price': (0.29728,), 'XRPUSDT_last_close_price': (0.29746,), 'XRPUSDT_last_quantity': (138.3,), 'XRPUSDT_bid_price': (0.29512,), 'XRPUSDT_bid_quantity': (10419.5,), 'XRPUSDT_ask_price': (0.29513,), 'XRPUSDT_ask_quantity': (485.6,), 'XRPUSDT_high_price': (0.312,), 'XRPUSDT_low_price': (0.266,), 'XRPUSDT_volume': (1478190048.7,), 'XRPUSDT_quote_volume': (432378019.148203,), 'XRPUSDT_open_time': (1609012754189.0,), 'XRPUSDT_close_time': 1609099154189.0}
```

I later pass this data off to my REST service as input_layer. Where I am taking just the values, converting it to a list, and sending it off. It's failing validation though because that list contains tuples for some reason and not all numerical values.

```
    aggregate_input = {
        "currency": currency['_id'],
        "time_of_aggregation": time_of_aggregation,
        "network_version": version['_id'],
        "input_layer": list(inputs.values())
    }
```

Can anybody explain what is going on? I've done some searching around. I've also tried converting all the values with floats with numpy before sending it to my restful service, but even numpy has issues because of the tuple values.

Comment: Remove the commas from the end of your lines.  Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You have `,` at the end of some lines, which makes your values a tuple

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so dumb... I have been looking at this for an hour and half.

Comment: @DylanDodds happens to the best of us haha